# how can i verify the self signed certificate using openssl library in C++?

Tags: c++, openssl, digital-signature, x509certificate

i need to verify the X509 v3 certificate .the Certificate is self signed so i have the private key and public key with me .

I tried

```
ki=X509_verify(Cert,X509_get_pubkey(Cert));
```

i always getting the Ki = -1 .
can any one tell me how to do this verification.

Comment: It should be mentioned that the documentation suggests that X509_verify should return 1 for success, and 0 for error. Therefore, -1 is 'Something else completely undefined'.  In other words, verification has not worked. (It didn't fail, and it didn't pass)

Comment: @Arafangion then can you guide me how to do verification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering my own question.
before call X509_verify(,) function 
  
   OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
this function set the digests algorithm in the local table which is used internally for verification.